# Jquery Mobile 1.4.0 + changePage() + custom select menu

Tags: jquery-mobile, menu

I am building an application using jquery mobile 1.4.0 / MVC.

I have just upgraded from jquery mobile 1.3.2

I have set the generic option for native menus to false:

> $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;

And the default Ajax navigation is kept to true:

> $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;

When I first load the application I can see all my items in the select menus as rendered by jquery without any problem. However, it would appear that after a call to **$.mobile.changePage()**, the select menus stop working - I click, tap, nothing shows. No error is flagged in the browser either.

It starts working again after I refresh the whole page.

If I switch the nativeMenu option to true, then I can see the menu items all the time.

I am starting to think that this is related to jquery mobile 1.4.0 as I have a demo site for the app with 1.3.2 and the problem described above doesn't exist there.

Has anyone faced this issue and found a solution to this?

Many thanks for reading

Vincent

Comment: Do you set `reloadPage` or `reload` to true when changing pages?

Comment: Hi. I have looked deeper in this. The issue also occurs when I am not using changePage - for instance if the previous page is a clickable listview. When I click on that it loads the URL and displays it but the drop down items stop showing... Any idea?

Comment: stop showing or they look native? are you using single or multi-page model?

Comment: @Omar: I am using a single page model. They simply stop showing, apart from the default selected item. Also I noticed on various different pages that I am certain were working before that they simply stopped working today after the update to jQM 1.4. I load the pages using their URL's with MVC @Url.Action("view", "controller")

Comment: Note that 1.4 has gone under many changes. for instance, `changePage` is now `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "URL");`. without more details, its difficult to pinpoint your problem.

Comment: @Omar: Sure. One example of a page with that issue is this: I have a page built with items listed with listviews: So you have a construction like : <li><a  href="@Url.Action("Edit", "User", new {id=item.TemplateId})">... At this point the drop downs I refer to work fine. I then "tap" or "click", it loads the URL in question (without me putting any javascript), and when the new page is rendered, the drop downs stop working.

Comment: I guess you need to disable Ajax. Are you sure Ajax was enabled when you used 1.3?

Comment: @Omar : 100%. I might have to restore jQM 1.3.2. I'm really struggling on this one. Thanks for your help anyway ;o)

Comment: I have restored jQM 1.3.2 and my menus / drop downs start working again... Odd. And no error that I can see on 1.4. Very strange.

Comment: @Omar: Hi. Finally found a way around this issue I kept having, although I didn't yet entirely find the cause for it. I have a layout built around a page, and in that page a header in which I place a drop down list. I find that for some reason, I have to remove that drop down from the DOM at "pagebeforeload" and that sorted all of the issues. Not only the drop down I removed is being re-created but also the others that stopped working are working again. Not sure this makes a lot of sense but that now seems to work.

Comment: Good news, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

(my rating is too low to leave a 'comment')

I had a somewhat similar issue.  I've used a 'custom select menu' in my registration form.  If there is an error on form submission and the form is reloaded for the user to make amendments then the custom select menu no longer works.

Setting the  to daja-ajax="false" stopped the issue.

In my very limited view I think there's something to do custom select menu's requiring a unique ID. You can't seem to have repeats of it on one page, or when a page is partially loaded via ajax.